# How are the abstract classes implemented which in collection.abc.* module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering that how the implementation mechanism work for tuple, list, or set data types. When I have checked the tuple data type with **help()** function, I can't see any inherited class from collection.abc module.

```
help(tuple)

Help on class tuple in module builtins:

class tuple(object)
# omitting the other details
```

When I was checking:

```
import collections

issubclass(tuple, collections.abc.MutableSequence) # False
issubclass(tuple, collections.abc.Sequence) # True

issubclass(list, collections.abc.MutableSequence) # True
issubclass(list, collections.abc.Sequence) # True
```

Both of two lines for list are correct because I know that MutableSequence is also subclass of Sequence abstract class.

I'm getting confused because as I mentioned above I couldn't see any inherited class from the collection.abc module within concrete tuple or list implementation. Long story short I try to find an explanation about implementation of abstract base classes for Python data types.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__

Comment: The implementation is written in python, if you want to take a look.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for your effort but the line you wrote neither an explanation nor a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `tuple` and `list` do not inherit from any collections abstract base class. Instead, the collections classes customize [instance and subclass checks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks), with the `class.__instancecheck__()` and `class.__subclasscheck__()` hooks.

These hooks are called whenever you use `isinstance()` or `issubclass()` with a class that implements them, and their result is returned:

```
>>> import collections.abc
>>> collections.abc.MutableSequence.__subclasscheck__(tuple)
False
>>> collections.abc.MutableSequence.__subclasscheck__(list)
True
```

Specifically, the hooks are implemented by the [`abc.ABCMeta` Abstract Base Class metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta), which abstracts the process. Your Abstract Base Class only needs to implement the [`__subclasshook__()` class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__); this is easier to implement, as the `__subclasscheck__` and `__instancecheck__` special methods must be implemented on a metaclass.

The `ABCMeta` implementation also includes a registry to add types to an ABC, with the [`ABCMeta.register()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register). The `tuple` and `list` classes are registered explicitly with the `Sequence` type, for example:

```
Sequence.register(tuple)
Sequence.register(str)
Sequence.register(range)
Sequence.register(memoryview)
```

Comment: at that case, what is the difference between subclassing and registration?

Comment: @vildhjarta: A subclass inherits the *implementation*. Registration only makes a statement that the right methods are present and implemented correctly.

Comment: @vildhjarta: the ABCs are implemented in Python and have base implementations for the methods. `list` and `tuple` are implemented in C code, their implementations are materially different and would be way too slow if they actually inherited from the base ABC implementations.